# Cutting a part of string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm actually working on program where I want to manually copy and paste a webpage source code and the program is supposed to find a certain part of the source code and cut it out from the rest of the string.

I can't find the way how to cut it out from the rest of the text.

So I have a string something like this:

```
"<b>abcdefgh qwertzuiop thepartineedtocut</b>abcdefght mnbvcxy"
```

And I need to get just:

```
"thepartineedtocut"
```

The problem is that it will not always be the same word but the words around it will not change. I hope you understand me.
Thanks.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Not clear.. if you want to cut "thepartineedtocut" from original text, you will result in text "thepartineedtocut" so what's the point?

Comment: If you want to work with/manipulate HTML, I suggest using a proper library like [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @KonradKokosa: I am pretty sure the original text is unknown, the above is just an example to illustrate what needs to be done.

Comment: @Neolisk, sure but the point is the provided example do not provide any pattern how to find the substring. It is not `<b>...</b>` content obviously.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: I guess the idea was that OP cannot explain the pattern any better than showing an example. Remember, English is not a native language for everyone. Technical English is even a bigger deal, something that comes with experience.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse html, but maybe this naive approach is sufficient:

If the rule is: "what is the string that is the last word in `<b>` ... `</b>`":

```
Dim myString = "<b>abcdefgh qwertzuiop thepartineedtocut</b>abcdefght mnbvcxy"
Dim result As String = Nothing
Dim bTokenStart = myString.IndexOf("<b>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
If bTokenStart >= 0 Then
    bTokenStart += "<b>".Length
    Dim bTokenEnd = myString.IndexOf("</b>", bTokenStart, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    If bTokenEnd >= 0 Then
        Dim bToken = myString.Substring(bTokenStart, bTokenEnd - bTokenStart)
        result = bToken.Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last()  ' thepartineedtocut
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
Dim input As String = "<b>abcdefgh qwertzuiop thepartineedtocut</b>abcdefght mnbvcxy"
Dim re As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(\w+)</b>")
Console.WriteLine(re.Match(input).Groups(1).Value) 'outputs: thepartineedtocut
```

The rule here is : find a word immediately before the closing `</b>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a combination of [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Mid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kyd8789%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'd recommend SubString instead of Mid, but the concept is sound.

Answer (score 0):

If the text never changes then:

```
Dim input As String = "<b>abcdefgh qwertzuiop thepartineedtocut</b>abcdefght mnbvcxy"

input = input.replace("<b>abcdefgh qwertzuiop ","").replace("</b>abcdefght mnbvcxy","")
```